# Why is it that sometimes the "active" field is not shown on meta?

Tags: support, statistics

I haven't experienced this on the main site but just today I've noticed that the "active" field is not displayed:

[image: Examples with and without "active" entries]

I even edited question #1, just in case it was due to inactivity, yet the field was still not displayed.

Anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Martijn Pieters explains this on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211074/167646):

> The 'activity' field only shows up if there are multiple posts on the page. In other words, only when there are *answers* will there be a 'active: *relative or absolute date*' entry on the right-hand side.
>
> This field is there to help you home in on *which* of the posts (the question or one of the answers) last changed.
>
> Take your question here for example. Before I posted this answer, there was no 'active' field present. Now that I posted it, the field showed up. The same applies to the sample question you linked to; there is an answer on that question too.

Comment: I almost thought you added the last part yourself because it fits perfectly here :)

Comment: *I haven't experienced this on the main site* it seems it means I was not paying attention :). Thanks!

Comment: @Adelin I think you probably haven't noticed it on the main site because its so much more busier so it doesn't take long for an answer to crop up, meta is however a lot quieter